# How to make an arrayAdapter display the contents of more than one array?

Tags: android, multidimensional-array, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a multidimentional arrayList.eg

```
arrayList 0 --> {startdate, duration, status}
          1 --> {startdate, duration, status}
          2 --> {startdate, duration, status}
```

I have bundled up this array and sent it to the next Activity. In this Activity i can pass the first index of arrayList to the adapter and it displays the data(Although it displayed 5 time instead of once, another problem).

My question is how can i pass more than one array to the adapter or get the adapter to iterate over more than one array?

In the following snippet array is the multidimensional array. I've hardcoded position(0) to pass to the adapter. How would i pass the other 7 arrays inside to the adapter.

```
public class GetRota extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = GetRota.class.getSimpleName();
    ListView listView;
    Intent intent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.getrotalayout);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.rotalist);
        intent = this.getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("rotaArrayBundle");

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayList array =  (ArrayList) bundle.get("rotaArray");             
        String record = array.get(0).toString();
        String[] itemsInRecord = record.split(",");
        String[] recordItem = new String[5];

       for(int x = 0; x < itemsInRecord.length; x++){

           Log.e(TAG, "token = " + itemsInRecord[x]);
           recordItem[x] = itemsInRecord[x];
      }

       MySimpleArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, recordItem);
       listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    }// end of onCreate


    private class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
          private final Context context;
          private final String[] values;

          public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
            super(context, R.layout.rotarowlayout, values);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
          }

          @Override
          public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rotarowlayout, parent, false);
           TextView startTime = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowstarttime);
           TextView duration = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowduration);
           TextView status = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowstatus);
           TextView name = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowclientname);

           startTime.setText("Start Time: " + values[0]);
           duration.setText("Duration:" + values[1]);
           status.setText("Status:" + values[2]);
           name.setText("Client:" + values[3] + values[4]);



            return rowView;
          }
        }   
    }// end of GetRota
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your own adapter by extending from BaseAdapter and then instead of passing an array of values to your adapter, pass the ArrayList itself. You can use the position value to access the right index in getView. This is how your code should look like

```
private class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
      private final Context context;
      private final ArrayList array;

      public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList array) {
        this.context = context;
        this.array = array;
      }

    public int getCount() {
        return array.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return array.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String[] values = array.get(position).toString();
        View rowView;

        if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                // attributes
            rowView = new View(context);
            // get layout from gridview_item.xml
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rotarowlayout, parent, false);
        } else {
            rowView = (View) convertView;
        }


       TextView startTime = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowstarttime);
       TextView duration = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowduration);
       TextView status = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowstatus);
       TextView name = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowclientname);

       startTime.setText("Start Time: " + values[0]);
       duration.setText("Duration:" + values[1]);
       status.setText("Status:" + values[2]);
       name.setText("Client:" + values[3] + values[4]);



        return rowView;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to subclass BaseAdapter and use that to do whatever you want with the data.  [Here is an article](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429) on creating a custom adapter.

Comment: ok thanks I've had a quick look, but will go through it later tonight. I'm not sure if it covers multidimensional arrays but thanks

Comment: It shows how to turn any data structure you like into a list adapter.  How that gets displayed it up to you at that point.